# How can you monitor for schema changes?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

In short, I want to monitor for schema changes to a database, specifically SQL Server.

I know there are tools which can compare a database to source control, but this is not what I am looking for. I just want something which I can run hourly/daily/weekly, and it tells me if any tables have changed (added, updated, deleted) since it [the app] last ran. I also don't want to install anything on the server, such as triggers.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: So you want something that doesn't compare changes, but also doesn't create any modules for tracking... I'm confused as to what you expect, then.

Comment: DDL triggers which saves the information in some service table.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the [Schema Change History Report](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/07/07/sql-server-ssms-schema-change-history-report) however often you want. This uses the default trace of your instance to report on schema changes, when they changed, and who changed them. This would be a very manual process, but you don't have many options considering you don't want to "*install*" anything on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce groups of objects to a hash... maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311969/check-for-changes-to-a-sql-server-database? You can reduce it to ONE hash or a series of hashes to help indicate where the change happened.